# is this right? Top End Rebuild on my 94 Harley Top End and using Synthetic Oil for the first 3,000 miles then told to switch to regular Harley oil

Tags: engine, motorcycle, oil

just rebuilt my 94 Harley Top End and using Synthetic Oil for the first 3,000 miles then told to switch to regular Harley oil.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm not really sure what you're asking here ... if you are looking for specific product recommendation, that would be off-topic for the site and I'd have to close the question. If you are looking for other specifics as far as what type or weight to use, please edit your question and include the information inside the question.

Comment: When I suggested you should edit the question, I wasn't suggesting you try to put it all in the title. Could you please edit this and put pertinent information in the body of the question and fix the title?

Comment: After the overhaul, use the recommended grade fully Synthetic oil regularly.

Answer (score -1):

---I own a '92 Heritage Custom--and from what I've read I would never ever put a synthetic in her--it may be ok for break-in, if you had the cylinders bored or honed-I would ask others and get as many opinions as possible-the issue is that the recommended oil for that vintage (as far as I know) is 20/50 (Dino oil being the safest) and that you can cause other problems like leaks by using the synthetic. Get as many opinions as you can and good luck.